# How to check whether a number is NSInteger or floating point in IOS?

Tags: iphone, ios

I need to check whether a value which is coming from the server is NSString , NSInteger or float. In case of string i am able to check.But how can we differentiate between a float and integer ?

Comment: Are you parsing string to integer/float/string ?

Comment: Please add more details about how you get this "value" from the server.

Comment: Add the value that are coming from server.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's how to do

```
NSNumber * n = //from somewhere
if (strcmp([n objCType], @encode(float)) == 0) {
    NSLog(@"this is a float");
} else if (strcmp([n objCType], @encode(int)) == 0) {
    NSLog(@"this is an int");
}
```

**EDIT**

OK, let's make it more generic

```
    NSNumber *anyNSObject = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.4];

    id obj = anyNSObject; //you can pass anything here as long as it is inherited from NSObject

    if ([obj isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
        NSLog(@"This is string");
    }

    if ([obj isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]) {
        NSLog(@"This is NSNumber");

        if (strcmp([obj objCType], @encode(float)) == 0) {
            NSLog(@"this is a float");
        } else if (strcmp([obj objCType], @encode(int)) == 0) {
            NSLog(@"this is an int");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Although the type of input is unclear, this should work in most cases :)

Answer (score 2):

(I assume you are parsing some string from the server. And convert it to the int/float/string locally.)

Both the client and server must agree on some specification. For example, the floating point must come with decimal point. Or the result has one more field to describe the concrete type. Because you can't infer the actual type from the string value.

To elaborate, if you see "9.000" from the server. You don't know whether it is int or float. But if you agree that the existence of decimal point implies floating number. It will become float, but not int. You can use this fact to make your parser.

(Important) Moreover, parsing floating point from string usually has numerical error. If the server has less floating point accuracy than the client, the client cannot obtain the exact float value. You should parse it as fixed point instead of floating point.

Answer (score 1):

Simple way will be :

```
NSRange range = [yourString rangeOfString:@"."];

if (range.length > 0){
  NSLog(@"Double value");
}
else {
  NSLog(@"Integer value");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do.

```objectivec
- (BOOL)isFloatNumber:(NSNumber *)value {
    if ([[value stringValue] containsString:@"."]) {
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

double var = 4.1;

```
if(ceil(var) == var){
      //Int value
    }else{
     //Float value
    }
```