# How to check whether input value is integer or float in Objective-c

Tags: objective-c

I am novice in Objective-c ,i want to know ,in  Objective-C, how can I check whether input value is integer or float like 2, 3.00,

```
here 2 is integer and 3.00 is float data-type
```

how can i find-out it.Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you need to know, is the difference important?

Comment: yes @Wain i want to develop a polynomial program . Buy using that user can find out and kind of polynomial value. Assume , 3x3 - 5x2 + 6 and ..(3.31 x 108 + 2.01 x 107) their are two polynomial .First one is normal integer polynomial and second one is float-polynomial . i want to check ... user input belong in which polynomial ...

Comment: And how are you taking the user input in?

Comment: Like 3x^2+2x-6,  here,  3 is Firstinput, 2 is sexondinput as well as 6 is constValue..  User can also set x value..  I want to check each ad every value moreover. +, - also..  after all checking output will come..  this is raw think.  Will be update... You want to assist me over mail also.. If you want...   ferrakkem@gmail.com,  it my mail address

Comment: @Wain I think you got my point. ?

Comment: This was already answered here, I suggest you check it out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15020989/how-to-check-whether-a-number-is-nsinteger-or-floating-point-in-ios

Comment: Just assume all numbers are floating point.  You're going to have to convert them anyway to solve.

Answer (score 1):

So, the simplest solution is probably to check each string input for a period (`.`) character (possibly also checking for another number after it) because checking that the number `3.00` and `3` are different is quite hard (because they are only different if you tell them to be).

The easiest way to do that would be with `rangeOfString:`.